# date and time values for prediction

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, time-series, prediction

I'm working on a project for predicting values between -1 to 1 by date and time. 
I have a dataset of 100 predicted values and I'm splitting the data to 70 training set and 30 test set .
the data contains: Date and time (2019-04-25 21:00:00) and Prediction (-1 to 1 values)

When I'm trying to call `fit_transform` on train set, I'm getting an error:

> "ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[-1. -1. 
>   1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.  1. -1.  1. -1.  1.
>     1. -1.  1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.  1. -1. -1. -1.  1. -1. -1. -1. -1.  -1. -1.  1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.  1. -1. -1. -1.  1. -1. -1. -1.  -1. -1.]. Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it
>   contains a single sample."

```
   df = pd.read_csv(file_to_read)
   df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
   df=df.set_index(['Date'],drop=True)
   print(df.head(size))

   #Index for prediction 
   pred_index=int((size*30)/100)
   from_specific_time=df.index[pred_index]

   split_date=pd.Timestamp(from_specific_time)
   df=df['Predict']
   train=df.loc[split_date:]
   test=df.loc[:split_date]

   plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
   ax=train.plot()
   test.plot(ax=ax)
   plt.legend(['train','test'])

   scaler=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1))
   train_scaler=scaler.fit_transform(train)
   test_scaler=scaler.transform(test)
```

I want to create a time-series by exact times in csv and then predict the test values .. and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong..
btw, I'm following the tutorial: https://towardsdatascience.com/an-introduction-on-time-series-forecasting-with-simple-neura-networks-lstm-f788390915b

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried **train.values.reshape(-1, 1)** before using the MinMaxScaler ?

Answer (score 0):

The error states that it needs a 2D array. So try converting the array into 2D,

```
train = ([train])
train_scaler = scaler.fit_transform(train)
```